# Python 3.5: Date/Time in a List

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

My source code -

```
from datetime import datetime
result = []
now = datetime.now()
result.append(now)
print (result)
```

In the output screen, this is what I get -

```
[datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 11, 18, 42, 25, 787837)]
```

How do I get rid of the datetime.datetime ?

Comment: How do you want your output to look like?

Comment: [(2016, 3 , 11, 18, 42, 25, 787837)]

Comment: So probably you want an object similar to datatype with custom transformation to string, don't you? Otherwise you just make tuple and print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` will call `str()` on what you print, and because you print a list the list will call `repr()` on its content.

You can use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to format your datetime.

Something like:

```
formatted = [_date.strftime("(%Y, %m, %d)") for _date in results]
print("[{}]".format(", ".join(formatted)))
```

should work.

The string you give to `strftime` works as a "template", whereas special characters are replaced by the year, day, ... . For a list of these take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could you give me an example of how to use it? I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: That's working, but there's no time along with the date.

Comment: You have to alter the template string so that it suits you. All format codes are listed [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for taking the time to answer.